# PHP preg_replace removes the whitespace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string:

```
$test = "Test string<i> hello world</i>."
```

Then I am running

```
$test = preg_replace('/(<i>{1}\s*)([\w*\d*\D*\W*\x*\O*\S*\s*]*?)(<\/i>{1})/', '<italic>$2</italic>', $test);
```

And the result is

```
Test string<italic>hello world</italic>.
```

Why is the whitespace before the hello world lost?

Here is an example http://pastebin.com/SXFhsCGK.

Thank you.

Comment: `[\w*\d*\D*\W*\x*\O*\S*\s*]` Ouch. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to match everything between <i> and </i>. The goal is to replace <i> tags by <italic> tags

Comment: Sure, this can be done, but the question is not how to do it differently, but why this happens.

Comment: This consumes Your whitespace after <i>: `(<i>{1}\s*)`. BTW I guess `<i>{1}` isn't what You intend, it says "match the `<`, then match the `i` and then match (exactly one, which is default) `>`".

Comment: `preg_replace('%<(/?)i>%', '<$1italic>', $test)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

As @Reeno puts it in the comments, replacing the `<i>` tags by `<italic>` ones directly is the way to go (assuming they're all tags you want to replace):

```
preg_replace('%<(/?)i>%', '<$1italic>', $test)
```

**What was wrong with your regex**

The space is lost because it is matched by the `\s*` in `<i>{1}\s*`, so it's not in the capturing group.

Also, writing `[\w\W...]` means "match any character that is either alphanumeric OR any character that is not alphanumeric"... So basically, match everything.

And the `{1}` quantifier is (always?) useless (`>{1}` is equivalent to `>`).

Heuristically, what you wanted to do was use this regex (`s` is so that the dot matches newline too):

```
~<i>(.*?)</i>~s
```